# JDialog dissappears when I switch between two windows

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I'm trying to make a simple JDialog, which asks the user for input in the form of 3 text fields, and it displays correctly and its PropertyListener works perfectly fine, I haven't assigned a parent for the JDialog in it's constructor, so I'm guessing by default the parent is set to be the ancestor of all the components in my applet. However, when I change from the applet to, say a firefox window and when I click back on my applet, the JDialog has disappeared. Would I need to set a certain property to the JDialog to make sure it stays even when I switch windows. The starnge thing is that I think the dialog is still up, but invisible, because when another dialog appears after the first has disappeared, both dialog appear at once(the first dialog reappearing). MY code for the JDialog is just below:

```
private void addQuestion() {
        questionTextField = new TextField(50);

        Object[] componentsArray = {"Question:", questionTextField, "MQLYes:", mqlYesTextField, "MQLNo:", mqlNoTextField};
        Object[] options = {"Enter", "Cancel"};
        addQuestionDialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(),"Add question");
        addQuestionPane = new JOptionPane(componentsArray, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);

        int x = getX() + getWidth()/2, y = getY() + getHeight()/2;

        addQuestionDialog.setContentPane(addQuestionPane);
        addQuestionDialog.setResizable(false);
        addQuestionDialog.setSize(300,210);
        addQuestionDialog.setVisible(true);
        addQuestionDialog.setLocation(x, y);
        addQuestionDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        addQuestionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    String prop = e.getPropertyName();

    if (addQuestionDialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == addQuestionPane) && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop) || JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))) {
        Object value = addQuestionPane.getValue();

        if (value == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
            //ignore reset
            return;
        }

        //Reset the JOptionPane's value.
        //If you don't do this, then if the user
        //presses the same button next time, no
        //property change event will be fired.
        addQuestionPane.setValue(
            JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);

        if (value.equals("Enter")) {
            String questionTypedText = questionTextField.getText();
            String mqlYesTypedText = mqlYesTextField.getText();
            String mqlNoTypedText = mqlNoTextField.getText();

            sqlModel.addQuestion(questionTypedText, mqlYesTypedText, mqlNoTypedText);
            questionTextField.setText("");
            mqlYesTextField.setText("");
            mqlNoTextField.setText("");
        } else { //user closed dialog or clicked cancel
            addQuestionDialog.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked the code several time and I don't see any issues with it, and the dialogs do what they're supposed to do, so I'm guessing there's a special addQuestion.set...(Object setValue) method which I should be adding in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I need to set a certain property to the JDialog to make sure it stays even when I switch windows.

Yes.

> I haven't assigned a parent for the JDialog in it's constructor,

and that would be the problem. The dialog will be visible whenever the owner of the dialog is visible, so you need to specify the owner JFrame.

Comment: can I ask which method I should use so the dialog remains open, and is there any way around not declaring a parent for the dialog?

Comment: `can I ask which method I should use so the dialog remains open` - use the appropriate constructor. `is there any way around not declaring a parent for the dialog?` then you get the behaviour you just described, which you don't want. What is the problem with specifying the parent JFrame???

Comment: Any reason you're avoiding setting a parent?

Comment: The JFrame is in another file, and the Dialog is contained inside a JPanel which i contained inside the JFrame. If only I could set the panel as the parent *sigh

Comment: I create a new instance of the JPanel inside the file containing the JFrame, but I could move around my code to put both pieces in a single file, I was just wondering if there was a way around it

Comment: @AndrewBrick, `The JFrame is in another file,` - so how do you display the dialog? I'm guessing you click on a JButton or something? Then you can use the `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...)` method to get the frame. The code doesn't have to be in the same source file.